# Что такое перечисляемые и неперечисляемые свойства объектов?

Tags: javascript

В книге Дэвида Флэнагана в главе "Свойства и методы универсального класса Object" столкнулся с термином перечисляемые и не перечисляемые свойства. Раз есть перечисляемые свойства значит есть и не перечисляемые свойства. Хотелось бы узнать что это за свойства и чем отличаются. В интернете не нашел по этой теме ничего подходящего. Поэтому прошу помощи здесь. Всем заранее спасибо.

---

Выдержка из книги:

> Обратите внимание: все свойства объекта, определяемые пользователем, являются перечислимыми. Неперечислимыми обычно являются унаследованные свойства (тема наследования свойств рассматривается в главе 9), поэтому практически всегда этот метод возвращает то же значение, что и метод `hasOwnProperty()`.

Comment: можете добавить цитату из книги?

Comment: добавил, смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: эм... я не вижу слов _перечислимый тип данных_

Comment: обратите внимание на слова - **являются перечислимыми** - мне вот этот момент не понятен

Comment: http://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/js_theory/level1/1_7.php вот тут посмотрите - речь про `enumerable`

Comment: В языке JS нет перечисляемого типа данных, в отличие от [многих других языков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type). В данном случае говорится о том, что бы перечислить содержимое объекта. Однако следует понимать, что у объекта есть свойства, которые ему могут не принадлежать(наследование по прототипу) и быть не перечисляемыми.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В цитате речь идет о свойствах объекта.

Они могут быть перечислимыми, и не перечислимыми.

Если свойство перечислимое, то при обходе в цикле `for..in` его можно будет получить, если не перечислимое - нельзя.

Например:

```js
var o = {
  e: "prop"
};

for (var i in o) {
  document.write('свойство "' + i + '" перечислимое');
}

document.write('<br/>свойство toString не перечислимое: '+o.toString)
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Логично предположить, что речь идёт о массивах и объектах с подобной семантикой.

Т. е. нечто, содержащие свойства-индексы и (скрытое) свойство `length`.

---

Если говорить о ES6, то сюда можно отнести генераторы, а также вспомнить `Symbol.iterator` и цикле for of, позволяющем итерироваться по коллекции.

PS: Книгу не читал.

Comment: судя по обновлению - имелись ввиду enumerable и not enumerable property

Comment: @Grundy, я писал до обновления вопроса.

Comment: ага :-) но вопрос обновился :) стоит обновить и ответ :-) дополнить.

Comment: @Grundy, чем дополнить? Скорее удалить? Тогда подожду -3, раз уж минус кто-то поставил.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [**ТУТ**](https://codepen.io/magistr4815/pen/LmwXRQ) изложил всю инфу которую нашёл по собственным и перечисляемым свойствам объекта. 
Так же рассказал как сделать свое СОБСТВЕННОЕ свойство!

```
let object = {
  enumProp1: '1',
  enumProp2: '2',
  enumProp3: '3',
};

// Явное определение НЕПЕРЕЧИСЛЯЕМОГО (собственного) свойства
Object.defineProperty(object, 'key', {
  enumerable: false, // - флаг который какраз делает его НЕ перечисляемым!!! если изменить на true, то будет перечисляемым!!!
});

for (key in object) {
  document.write(`${key}<br>`); // все перечисляемые свойства можно перечислить For
}

//Так же не перечисляемыми свойствами являются те, которые унаследованы от дургих или просто ядвляются внутренними и закрытыми
document.write('<br/>свойство toString не перечисляемое (собственное): '+ object.toString);

// БОЛЬШЕ ИНФЫ ТУТ https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties
```